# How to specify coversion for Firebase ad_click event in AdWords

Tags: android, firebase, integration, google-ads-api

I want to make a report that shows how much money I spent advertising application vs how much revenue I make from the banners inside it.

I thought that using Firebase-AdWords integration this can be done but unfortunately haven't find any solution. I thought that making Firebase's ad_click event as a Conversion will tell Adwords this info and then I could make report in Adwords but it appears that ad_click cannot be set to Conversion.

Does anyone got any better idea?